# How do I count the number of observations with the same clustering based on two grouping variables?

Tags: sql, hive, hiveql

In HiveQL, how do I count the number of `id` that have the same grouping based on both `group1` and `group2`?

```
+-----+--------+--------+
| id1 | group1 | group2 |
+-----+--------+--------+
|   1 | Z      | a      |
|   2 | Z      | a      |
|   3 | Z      | b      |
|   4 | Z      | c      |
|   5 | Y      | d      |
+-----+--------+--------+
```

The result returned should be 3, since we should take the max of {(Z,a)(Z,b)(Z,c)}, which is 2, and max of {(Y,d)}, which is 1.

I've tried to code this in HiveQL using subqueries without success. Any hints would be appreciated.

Comment: how did you get 3 ? did you sum the ids ?

Comment: Yeah, that's the goal. Still thinking about how to code this though

Comment: why 3 | Z      | b      |
|   4 | Z      | c      are  not part of your result ?

Comment: Clarified my question. We should take the max of {(Z,a)(Z,b)(Z,c)}, which is 2, and max of {(Y,d)}, which is 1.

Comment: still not clear , please update your output table as per you requirement

Comment: the result should be a single number rather than a table. the table i included before was meant to help clarify the intermediate steps, but i removed it because it seems to complicate things

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125760/discussion-between-arunakiran-nulu-and-user2205916).

Answer (score 0):

Finally figured it out using SQL Fiddle. Try making the toy example with:

```
CREATE TABLE test
(`id` int, `group1` varchar(7), `group2` varchar(7));
INSERT INTO test
    (`id`, `group1`, `group2`)
VALUES
    (1, 'Z', 'a'),
    (2, 'Z', 'a'),
    (3, 'Z', 'b'),
    (4, 'Z', 'c'),
    (5, 'Y', 'd');
```

Running the query below returns 3.

```
SELECT SUM(d.max_val) 
  FROM(SELECT MAX(c.count) as max_val, c.group1, c.group2 
       FROM (SELECT COUNT(*) AS count, group1, group2
             FROM test
             GROUP BY group1, group2) c
GROUP BY c.group1, c.group2) d
```